# Is it possible to send email from localhost?

Tags: go, smtp

My goal is to create a `SMTP server` to send an email from `noreply@myname.com` containing OTP.

The problem is, I code on my personal computer. Therefore, no public address or domain, yet. I tried to send email to myname@gmail.com, but I can't find it on the spam, or the inbox folders.

What I've did:

1. run the go-smtp server. `$ go run cmd/server/main.go`
2. run the go-smtp client. `$ go run cmd/client/main.go`

The go-smtp server output

```
(base) jason@Jasons-Mac-mini server % go run main.go
2022/09/23 13:35:38 Starting server at :1025
2022/09/23 13:56:06 Mail from: test@localhost
2022/09/23 13:56:06 Rcpt to: // email redacted for stackoverflow
2022/09/23 13:56:06 Data: This is the email body
```

The go-smtp client output

```
(base) jason@Jasons-Mac-mini client % go run main.go
2022/09/23 13:56:06 Mail sent! time elapsed: 1.988625ms
```

cmd/client/main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/emersion/go-smtp"
)

func main() {
    start := time.Now()

    // Connect to the remote SMTP server.
    c, err := smtp.Dial("localhost:1025")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Set the sender and recipient first
    if err := c.Mail("test@localhost", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err := c.Rcpt("jasonong713@gmail.com"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Send the email body.
    wc, err := c.Data()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    _, err = fmt.Fprintf(wc, "This is the email body")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = wc.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Send the QUIT command and close the connection.
    err = c.Quit()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Println("Mail sent! time elapsed:", time.Since(start))
}
```

cmd/server/main.go

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/emersion/go-smtp"
    "github.com/godataid/sendemail"
)

func main() {
    be := &sendemail.Backend{}

    s := smtp.NewServer(be)

    s.Addr = ":1025"
    s.Domain = "localhost"
    s.ReadTimeout = 10 * time.Second
    s.WriteTimeout = 10 * time.Second
    s.MaxMessageBytes = 1024 * 1024
    s.MaxRecipients = 50
    s.AllowInsecureAuth = true

    log.Println("Starting server at", s.Addr)
    if err := s.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}
```

backend.go

```
package sendemail

import "github.com/emersion/go-smtp"

type Backend struct{}

// Authenticate a user. Return smtp.ErrAuthUnsupported if you don't want to
// support this.
func (be *Backend) Login(state *smtp.ConnectionState, username, password string) (smtp.Session, error) {
    return nil, smtp.ErrAuthUnsupported
}

// Called if the client attempts to send mail without logging in first.
// Return smtp.ErrAuthRequired if you don't want to support this.
func (be *Backend) AnonymousLogin(state *smtp.ConnectionState) (smtp.Session, error) {
    return &Session{}, nil
}
```

session.go

```
package sendemail

import (
    "io"
    "log"

    "github.com/emersion/go-smtp"
)

type Session struct{}

// Discard currently processed message.
func (s *Session) Reset() {}

// Free all resources associated with session.
func (s *Session) Logout() error {
    return nil
}

// Set return path for currently processed message.
func (s *Session) Mail(from string, opts smtp.MailOptions) error {
    log.Println("Mail from:", from)
    return nil
}

// Add recipient for currently processed message.
func (s *Session) Rcpt(to string) error {
    log.Println("Rcpt to:", to)
    return nil
}

// Set currently processed message contents and send it.
func (s *Session) Data(r io.Reader) error {
    if b, err := io.ReadAll(r); err != nil {
        return err
    } else {
        log.Println("Data:", string(b))
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: To send email to Google, you have to connect to Google's SMTP server. Your local SMTP server can forward the messages to Google (in which case it would typically be called a mail transfer agent, or MTA), but I don't see any attempt to do so in your code.

Comment: @Peter `but I don't see any attempt to do so in your code.` do you mean SMTP server is not the MTA? my understanding of mailing is that `a sender send email -> to SMTP (mail.domain.com) -> to SMTP (smtp.gmail.com) -> to IMAP3 -> to recipient`.

Comment: If you want to send email to gmail.com, then you (or something on your behalf) have to connect to the SMTP server for gmail.com (according to the MX DNS record). That doesn't happen in the code above. How many SMTP servers are in-between the sender and gmail.com's server isn't important.

Comment: If you expected github.com/emersion/go-smtp to automatically forward the email to Google, then no, that doesn't happen.